# Checklist on table view won't work

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitableview

I have a table View that when a cell is added, it won't work like the cells that are already on the app. When I press the new cell, my program crashes, I get this error:
"SIGABRT"

And here is my code for when the cell is pressed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    [self setCurrentChosenFund: [self.cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [self setSelectedCell: [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    if  ([self.currentChosenFund valueForKey:@"Selected"] == [NSNumber 
    numberWithBool:YES])

    {
        //selectedCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checklist.png"];
        [self.selectedCell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [self.currentChosenFund setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] 
     forKey:@"Selected"]; // ERROR IS ON THIS LINE :(
    }

    else

    {          
        //selectedCell.imageView.image = nil;  
        [self.selectedCell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [self.currentChosenFund setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] 
     forKey:@"Selected"];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.cells forKey:@"funds"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

The code for the save: method is:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
CheckListPracticeViewController * obj = (CheckListPracticeViewController     
         *)self.parentViewController;
[obj.cells insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:textField.text      
forKey:@"name"] atIndex:0]; 

// [obj.cells insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

OK so I added this line of code to my saveButton: method:

```
    [self.currentChosenFund setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]    
             forKey:@"Selected"];
```

I still get the app to crash! I've tried setting this to both YES and NO but it will not work.

Comment: What is the message when it crashes?  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Can you please post the entire error message?

Comment: Is `self.currentChosenFund` instance of mutable collection ?

Comment: Yea the whole message is "Thread 1: Program recieved signal:SIGABRT"

and YEs currentChosenFund is a mutable array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a comment than an answer, though it may turn out to be both. It makes more logical sense to use a `BOOL` for the key `Selected`.

Alternately, you can use

```
if ([[self.currentChosenFund valueForKey:@"Selected"] boolValue]) {
}
```

to avoid the comparison.

EDIT: Based on the comments, I believe the problem is with your `saveButton` method. You are not setting an object for the key "Selected", so when you go to retrieve it, you get an error. To fix this, set the default value to something in this method.

Comment: it is thats how i set it up in the plist

Comment: the problem is that after i add the new cell to my tableView, i try to select it (like a checklist) so a checkmark appears, but the program crashes when i select the _NEW_ cell!

Comment: @kurt: Then you've posted the wrong code for us. Please post the entire error message.

Comment: i did just above this answer it says : "Thread 1: Program recieved signal:SIGABRT" This appears on the line of code :

`        [self.currentChosenFund setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"Selected"];
`

Comment: @kurt: (1) I mean post the back trace. (2) I don't know what you mean when you write "the _NEW_ cell". Does this mean you are adding a cell? Or it works the first time you select a cell and not the second?

Comment: Please show us the currentChosenFund method. My guess is you have a missing retain statement on the currentChosenFund object.

Comment: @sosborn currentChosenFund is an NSMutableArray. @PengOne yes exactly i am adding a new cell. There are 2 pages, the first has a tableView and the second has a textField and when a user presses the save button, it adds the text to the tableView and this new cell, when pressed, crashes the program, when in fact its supposed to add a checkmark when pressed and when pressed a second time, its supposed to delete the check mark.

Comment: Agree with kurt, post the backtrace - otherwise we are trying to guess where the crash happened. Generally speaking the backtrace will give you all of the info you need to figure this out.

Comment: i would be glad to post the backtrace, but im not sure what that is.. Are you talking about the stack??

Comment: @kurt: POST THE BACK TRACE. If you have a different method that creates a new cell, then we need to see that code as well. You're not giving enough information for someone to help you.

Comment: i dont know what a back trace is, but the method i used to save the data to the table view is :

- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    CheckListPracticeViewController * obj = (CheckListPracticeViewController *)self.parentViewController;
    [obj.cells insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:textField.text forKey:@"name"] atIndex:0]; 
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

this method saves the data and ads it to the tableView on the first page. Is this enough code or would you like more? Thanks for the help guys :D

Comment: @kurt: please post this in the question. It's difficult to read unformatted code. Also, I think I see the problem. Check my answer again in a minute.

Comment: oh ok let me try this real quick and ill let you know how it turns out. ill try setting the default value to NO.

Comment: ok i tried setting the value to both yes and NO but it still crashes! do you have any more ideas?